# which face area should be cropped out for recognition

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

I am preparing face recognition dataset. I dont know the range of the bounding box I should use for cropping faces out of images. Should I leave some space around the head or just crop the tight area containing only facial features? Could someone paste a sample? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Face recognition datasets can be used for this main training/testing tasks:

1. **face detection** - here i can recommend to use uncropped images, so you can use natural background, that is required by some algorithms
2. **face alignment/facial landmark detection** - here the face can be rotated left/right much, so its good to have space about 1/2 of face width around it. this will make it possible to align faces to make center of face become the center of image, while left/right faces will take most of left/right area of image
3. **face features extraction** - DNN, LBP or other algorithms require only the area where the features exists
4. **classification** (emotions/attributes) - if the classification is not based on the previously extracted features and takes image - it will be to have some area around of face.

If you want to use your dataset for all this tasks - do not crop at all, and only save face region as annotations into some textual format (json/csv/xml...) for future processing

You can take a look on some classical datasets here:
[LFW](http://vis-www.cs.umass.edu/lfw/), [iBug](http://ibug.doc.ic.ac.uk/resources/300-W/), [other](http://www.face-rec.org/databases/)